# Typescript Error Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm working on a piece of code in Typescript, and came across this below issue that I can't make much sense as to why it's happening.

The below code block triggers an `Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'` error at compile.

```
interface A {
    x: number | string
}

const a1: A[] = [{x: 1}, {x: 'a'}]
const b: number[] | string[] = ['a', 'b']

const a2 = a1.filter(a => b.includes(a.x))
```

However; if I were to use `(number | string)[]` when declaring/assigning `b`, it works fine.

I checked the definition file for `includes` (`Array<T>.includes(searchElement: never, ...`), but that also didn't make sense because I thought that the generic `T` would encompass `number[] | string[]`.

I would appreciate if someone could shine a light as to why the `Array<T>` doesn't cover `number[] | string[]` but covers `(number | string)[]`.

Comment: `number[] | string[]` is either an array of all numbers or an array of all strings. `(number | string)[]` is an array of elements each of which may either be a number or a string. Any array that meets the first definition will meet the second, but the opposite is not true.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your reply. It seems that I made a typo in the code block. Sorry about that. The question and code should make a bit more sense now. So shouldn't `a.x` be comparable to each element of `b`? Because it's not like a single `string` to `number` comparison of which the result would always be false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type you set for `b` is `number[] | string[]`. This means that its type will be *either* an array of numbers (`number[]`) *or* an array of strings (`string[]`) - which exactly depends on the data you initialise the variable with.

When you do:

```js
const b: number[] | string[] = ['a', 'b'];
```

You actually set its type as `string[]` - this variable `b` now has nothing to do with numbers and is simply an array of strings.

Then you go ahead and do:

```js
const a2 = a1.filter(a => b.includes(a.x));
```

So, for each valuе of `a1` - which may be a `string` or a `number`, you check whether it exists in the array `b`. And as explained above, `b` is an array of strings *only*. And you cannot pass a `number | string` to `includes()`, which for this array expects only a `string` argument (this array is `Array<string>`). Hence the compiler error.

---

Now, for the other case you suggest:

```js
const b: (number | string)[] = ['a', 'b'];
```

This defines an array of the type `number | string`, that is, *every one of its elements* can be a different type - either a `number` or a `string`. So you can have, for example:

```js
const b: (number | string)[] = [1, 'b'];
```

It just happens that in your definition, all your elements (the two of them) are the same type - `string`.

Now when you get to the call to `includes()`, the situation is very different. Since your array can now hold both numbers and strings, `include()` would happily work with both those types (this array is `Array<number | string>`), and `a.x` can be both types.